# How to click a span Accordion with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, css-selectors

I have been trying to use selenium python to click the Element1 or Element2 button in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEjOt.png)

with this code :

```
element3=driver.find_elements_by_id("span.jump_1").click

element3=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#jump_1 > button").click
```

I have tried several `selectors`, `xpath`..nothing seems working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//h3[@id='Element_1']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@id='Element_1']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h3[@id='Element_1']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@id='Element_1']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@id='Element_1']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Also if the `id` is `unique`, I would advise you to use `id` instead of `xpath`.

Also, I do not see Element 2 in HTML that you've shared.